# Power BI DAX to find Data within specific period

Tags: powerbi, dax

The data is two tables 1 with Item name; Manager that was responsible for the item in a period; date from which they were on it (can be blank); date to which they were on it. And in Table 2 is the item name and when it was sold. What i need to find is a way to find in Power BI to add a column or measure that will show which manager was responsible for the item at that time.
[image: The image is from Excel just to simplify explanation.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution. although it takes up a lot of PC memory to process if the amount of data is large.

```
test = CALCULATE(
        VALUES('table1'[Manager]),
        FILTER('table1',
        'table1'[DayFrom] <= EARLIER('table2'[When])
        &&
        'table1'[DateTo] >= EARLIER('table2'[When] ) ) )
```

If there are blanks, as there were in my case, in table1 DateTo, i made a new column and used it instead with DAX:

```
 Date to Blanks = IF('Table1'[DayTo] = BLANK(),
    TODAY(), 'table1'[DayTo])
```

Answer (score 2):

Check my formula, it will return the result as expected, accept it if it help, thank you:)

```
Add Column = 
CALCULATE(
    MAX(Sheet1[Manager]),
        FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[item] = Sheet2[Item]),
            FILTER(ALL(Sheet1),Sheet1[Date from] <= EARLIER(Sheet2[When]) && Sheet1[Date to] >= Sheet2[When]))
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks, but it didn't quite work. The outcome didn't show what I was looking for in the cases where in table 1 the item was also in the date before. Your answer gave only the most recent result. I think I managed a working solution, will post it below as an answer to the thread.

Comment: Ya, you never show more condition, how will I know, anyway great you have found solution.